# disabling a button in c# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I have created two buttons in c#. Is there any way to deactivate a button if anything goes wrong in the other button's function. I am giving  a sample code fragment. There are two buttons. one is for connect and other is for browse files. I want to disable the browse button if the connectivity fails in the connect button. How to do this?

Sample code fragment:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Client:Form
{

public Client()
{
    Size = new Size(400, 380);
    Button connect = new Button();
    connect.Parent = this;
    connect.Text = "Connect";
    connect.Location = new Point(295, 20);
    connect.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
    connect.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonConnectOnClick);

     Button browse = new Button();
    browse.Parent = this;
    browse.Text = "Browse";
    browse.Location = new Point(220, 20);
    browse.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
    browse.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonbrowseOnClick);
   }
     void ButtonConnectOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)  
  {

    tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
  }
 [STAThread]
public static void Main()
{

 Application.Run(new Client());
}
}
```

**Another Question:**

Is there any way to reset the button (say, the browse button) activity at a certain time and wait for clicking again?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a global flag:

```
bool connectButtonBroken = false;
private void ButtonbrowseOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!connectButtonBroken)
    {
        //do code
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to reset the button activity at a certain time and wait for clicking again? @Cjen 1

Comment: yep quite easily just start a timer or do `thread.sleep(/*number of milliseconds*/);` and then set the flag to false again

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `connect` call in a Try/Catch block and disable the other button in the  `Catch`:

```
    catch (Exception)
    {
       ButtonConnect.Enabled = false;
    }
```

You should probably re-enable it just before the end of the `Try` with this:

```
    ButtonConnect.Enabled = true;
```

You will need to store a reference to your dynamically created  `Connect` button in a variable called `ButtonConnect` in a form level variable instead of a local one in the constructor for this to work.

Comment: is there any way to reset the button activity at a certain time and wait for clicking again?  @Bradley Uffner

Comment: If you enable the button after the `Connect` call while still inside the `Try` it will re-enable the browse button on successful connect.